# How to sort and count values ​when they are selected?

Tags: python, django

I send a request to the site https://swapi.dev/ the received data needs to be sorted:

Provide the functionality to count the occurrences of values (combination of values) for columns.
For example when selecting the columns ​date​ and ​homeworld​ the table should show the
counts as follows:

my code is not very good because I write something like this for the first time:

```
import requests
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.viewsets import ModelViewSet
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.response import Response
from datetime import datetime
from rest_framework import filters
from rest_framework.pagination import PageNumberPagination
from rest_framework.decorators import action


# class StarWarsAPIListPagination(PageNumberPagination):
#     page_size = 4
#     page_size_query_param = 'page_size'
#     max_page_size = 20


class StarView(APIView):
    # pagination_class = StarWarsAPIListPagination
    # filter_backends = (filters.OrderingFilter)
    # ordering_fields = ('name',)

    def get(self, request): 
        date = datetime.today()
        page = request.query_params.get('page', 1)
        url = f'https://swapi.dev/api/people/?page={page}'
        response = requests.get(url, date).json()
        return Response(response, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)


class StartDateView(APIView):

    def get(self, request): 
        date = datetime.today()
        page = request.query_params.get('page', 1)
        url = f'https://swapi.dev/api/people/?page={page}'
        response = requests.get(url).json()
        a = response['results'][0]['name']
        # a = response['results']
        # for i in range(len(a)):
        #     if a[i]["name"] == "R2-D2":
        #         return Response(a[i]['name'], status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand the question or the code.
In your code, what you are doing is creating an API with rest_framework. But your question is about sorting the data you request from a third party API.

Comment: @LaCharcaSoftware yes, from the code I created only a view and decided to rewrite the get method to get data from another site and skip the ordering by fields, I agree with such an explanation. Then I have another question, the data that I parse by default comes out 10 values: By default the table should only show the first 10 rows of the dataset, by clicking on a button “​Load more​” additionally 10 rows should be shown - reloading the page is fine.

next page = "https://swapi.dev/api/people/?page=2",